# Testing Flask having problems with python: from . import db

Tags: python, import

I'm testing a project found on the web that use Flask and Sqlalchemy and having problems on the import:

```
from . import db
```

The `__init__.py` file contains:

```
db=SQLAlchemy()
```

I'm working in windows with eclipse, python3.6 32 bit.
Any idea of the cause ?

Thank you

Comment: did you try just `import db`

Comment: Yes no luck still unresolved import.